# Get specific value of List Java

Tags: java, list, class, arraylist

You can run in online java compiler here https://www.codechef.com/ide choose java8.

Here is my code to search other value:
I want to print just '18' when I search 'Java'.
This code will return : [Person(Java,18)]
My question how to print just '18'?

```
import java.util.*;
class LinearSearchDemo { 
  public static void main (String[] args) { 
      List<Person> list = Arrays.asList(
                                  Person.create("Oscar", 16),
                                  Person.create("Oei", 17),
                                  Person.create("Java", 18)
                          );

      List<Person> result = searchIn( list, 
              new Matcher<Person>() { 
                  public boolean matches( Person p ) { 
                      return p.getName().equals("Java");
              }});

      System.out.println( result );
  }
  public static <T> List<T> searchIn( List<T> list , Matcher<T> m ) { 
      List<T> r = new ArrayList<T>();
      for( T t : list ) { 
          if( m.matches( t ) ) { 
              r.add( t );
          }
      }
      return r;
  }
}

class Person { 
  String name;
  int age;

  String getName(){ 
      return name;
  }
  int getAge() { 
      return age;
  }
  static Person create( String name, int age ) { 
      Person p = new Person();
      p.name = name;
      p.age = age;
      return p;
  }
  public String toString() { 
      return String.format("Person(%s,%s)", name, age );
  }    
}
interface Matcher<T> { 
  public boolean matches( T t );
}
```

Comment: Change your `toString()` method in `Person` class to: `return age;`.

Comment: `result.stream().forEach(p -> System.out.println(p.age))`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are printing `result` to `stdout`. The objects in this list are of type `Person`. That is the `Person.toString()` method is used to get a string representation of `result`.

As mentioned in the comments either change the `toString` method of Person to just return the value of `age` or iterate over the result and write the value of `age` to `stdout`.

Answer (score 2):

The method  `public static <T> List<T> searchIn( List<T> list , Matcher<T> m )` returns `List<T>`, in your case Person if you want to get person age
try  `result.stream().map(Person::getAge).forEach(System.out::println);`